# Access type flag of unknown void pointer based on two possible structs?

Tags: c, void-pointers, octree

I am currently working on my own octree in C. The tree will contain a few billion objects, so memory efficiency is key. To achieve this I currently use one struct with a flag and a union, but I think it is not clean and it is wasting space for the inner node because I only need an 8-bit flag but memory is being reserved for the 64-bit index. My code currently is as follows:

```
typedef struct _OctreeNode
{
    uint64_t location_code;
    union
    {
        uint8_t child_exists;
        uint64_t object_index;
    } data;
    uint8_t type;
} OctreeNode;
```

I would like to split this up into two different structs. One leaf node and one inner node. As follows:

```
typedef struct _OctreeInnerNode
{
    uint64_t location_code;
    uint8_t child_exists;
    uint8_t type;
} OctreeInnerNode;

typedef struct _OctreeLeafNode
{
    uint64_t location_code;
    uint64_t object_index;
    uint8_t type;
} OctreeLeafNode;
```

Now the problem arises with my unordered map based on the hash of the location code. It uses a void pointer, so storing two different structs is not a problem. I know a possibility would be to have the flag be the first element and dereference the pointer to the flag datatype to derive the type, like so:

```
typedef struct _OctreeLeafNode
{
    uint8_t type;
    uint64_t location_code;
    uint64_t object_index;
} OctreeLeafNode;

void
func(void* node)
{
    uint8_t type = *(uint8_t*)node;
    if (type == LEAF_NODE) {
        OctreeLeafNode* leaf_node = (OctreeLeafNode*)node;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way. Or is this not recommended? How would I be supposed to deal with multiple possibilities for structs and void pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a method that is used commonly in `C`.

But just put these field at **start** of structure (first field) and never change their position. In addition, you need to keep them in all your structures.

A common sample for this approach is the `version` field in structures (or `type` in your case). You can keep them at start of structure, and then check structure version by similar method. something like this:

```
struct _base {
    uint8_t ver;
};

#define TYPE_OLD 0
struct _a_old {
    struct _base info;
    uint8_t a;
};

#define TYPE_NEW 1
struct _a_new {
    struct _base info;
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
};
```

Now you can identify different types by casting your data to `struct _base` and checking `ver` field.

```
unsigned char* buf = ...
switch (((struct _base*)buf)->ver)
{
    case TYPE_OLD:
    {
        struct _a_old* old = (struct _a_old*)buf;
        // ...
        break;
    }
    case TYPE_NEW:
    {
        struct _a_new* old = (struct _a_new*)buf;
        // ...
        break;
    }
    default:
        // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! After thinking it through I think this might be the most consistent. Sneakily I had hoped there would be an even cleaner way, but I think this is already pretty clean in its own way.

Answer (score 4):

This will work, assuming the `type` field is first in each struct.  A pointer to a struct may safely be converted to a pointer to its first member, so assuming your structs look like this:

```
typedef struct _OctreeInnerNode
{
    uint8_t type;    // type goes first
    uint8_t child_exists;   // put uint8_t members together to keep size down
    uint64_t location_code;
} OctreeInnerNode;

typedef struct _OctreeLeafNode
{
    uint8_t type;   // type goes first
    uint64_t object_index;
    uint64_t location_code;
} OctreeLeafNode;
```

You can cast either a `OctreeInnerNode *` or a `OctreeLeafNode *` to a `uint8_t *`.  Then this is possible:

```
void func(void* node) {
    uint8_t type = *(uint8_t*)node;
    if (type == LEAF_NODE) {
        OctreeLeafNode *leafNode = node;
        ...
    } else if (type == INNER_NODE) {
        OctreeInnerNode *innerNode = node;
        ...
    }
}

...

OctreeLeafNode leaf = { LEAF_NODE, 2, 3 };
OctreeInnerNode inner = { INNER_NODE, 5, 1 };

func(&leaf);
func(&inner);
```

This is guaranteed as per section 6.7.2.1p15 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> Within  a  structure  object,  the  non-bit-field  members  and  the 
>   units  in  which  bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in
>   the order in which they are declared.  **A pointer to a structure 
>   object,  suitably  converted,  points  to  its  initial  member**  (or 
>   if  that  member  is  a bit-field,  then  to  the  unit  in  which  it
>   resides),  and  vice  versa.   There  may  be  unnamed padding within
>   a structure object, but not at its beginning

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Together with the reference, I can get a good understanding. After seeing the other example, I do think it might be better practice to use a struct as the base with the node type and the location_code. This way I can guarantee equal naming and avoid repetition.